# How to not print out Quote characters when creating a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that I'm creating in Azure Databrick using Python.  This is taking a data frame and generating a CSV file from it.  The problem is when there is an empty value in the data frame the output is 2 double quotes, i.e. "",

Example Output

```
L1Code  L1 Desc1    L1 Desc2    L1 Desc3    L2Code
Beverage    Beverage    ""  ""  Drink Blends
```

This is the code that I'm using to generate the file, where df is a Pandas dataframe that has already been created.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

def createCsvFile(data, rootPath, filePath):
  data.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "\t").option("quoteMode", "NONE").csv(rootPath + filePath + ".tmp")

  fileList = dbutils.fs.ls(rootPath + filePath + ".tmp/")

  for file in fileList:
    if file.name.endswith("csv"):
      filename = file.path
      dbutils.fs.cp(filename, rootPath + filePath + ".txt")

  dbutils.fs.rm(rootPath + filePath + ".tmp", recurse=True)


sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
data = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(df)
createCsvFile(data, '/mnt/adlsdata/Raw/Astute/', 'products')
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up needed to use the emptyValue option to make ti work

```
  data.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "\t").option("quoteMode", "NONE").option("quote", u'\u0000').option("nullValue", "").option("emptyValue", "").csv(rootPath + filePath + ".tmp")
```